# Function in invalid State : Oracle with Jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a query in java string. What i need to do is fire that query by jdbc.
Query is:

```
String strQuery= " CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CLOSE_DATE ( PARAM_DOCUMENT_ID IN NUMBER ) 
     RETURN DATE AS
      V_CLOSE_DATE DATE;
     BEGIN
       SELECT MAX(TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT.CLOSE_DATE_TIME) INTO V_CLOSE_DATE  
       FROM TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT  WHERE TOP_LEVEL_ELEMENT.DOCUMENT_ID = PARAM_DOCUMENT_ID; 
       RETURN V_CLOSE_DATE; 
     END GET_CLOSE_DATE;";
```

I am using JDBC

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(strQuery);
```

The query gets executed successfully but when I try to use this function it throws an an exception saying the GET_CLOSE_DATE function is in invalid state. I have also tried firing

```
alter function GET_CLOSE_DATE compile;
```

immediately after firing the create function query. Both are executed successfully but still the the function remains in invalid state. Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command to see what, if any errors are associated with this function:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user_errors 
 WHERE name = 'GET_CLOSE_DATE';
```

EDIT:

It might be the embedded CR/LF's in your string. Try concatenating your SQL string, as in:

```
String strQuery= " CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CLOSE_DATE ( PARAM_DOCUMENT_ID IN" +
                 " NUMBER) RETURN DATE AS " +
                 " V_CLOSE_DATE   DATE " +
...
```

Comment: It is giving the error message as :PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor external language

Comment: do u have any clue regarding this ?

Comment: What line number did it report?

Comment: You suspected it right, I had CR/LF at the end of my sting. I removed them and it compiled successfully. Thanks a lot.